# Why Wolfram-Alpha (W-A) said that $\lim_{x \to \infty} e^{\sqrt{x}}\cdot\text{sinc}(x) = 0\,$??

Tags: real-analysis, limits, functions, exponential-function, absolute-convergence

Why Wolfram-Alpha (W-A) said that $\lim_{x \to \infty} e^{\sqrt{x}}\cdot\text{sinc}(x) = 0\,$, if $\,\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{e^{\sqrt{x}}}{x^n} = \infty$ for any $n\gg 0$??

I have tried the first one in W-A and it show that its value is zero [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Limit%28e%5Esqrt%28x%29*sinc%28x%29%2Cx-%3Einf%29), even when it plot [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+e%5E%28sqrt%28x%29%29*sinc%28x%29+from+x%3D0+to+200) diverges ¯_(ツ)_/¯

Even, W-A says that $\int_0^\infty e^{\sqrt{x}}\text{sinc}(x)\,dx = 3.41751$ as you can see [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int_0%5Einf+%28e%5E%28sqrt%28x%29%29%29*sinc%28x%29*dx)... It must be diverging also, isn' it??

Is counter-intuitive that a function $\neq 0$ of the form $\text{sinc}(x) =$ $\frac{\text{bounded range}\,\in \, \left[-1;\, 1\,\right]}{x}$ makes converge the function $e^{\sqrt{x}}$ when no inverse of a polynomial can $\frac{1}{x^n}$, no matter how big their exponent $n > 1$ is.

I would like to know why W-A says that is "true" for the "sinc function" (since W-A is actually really good at math): Is "truly" a "mistake"?? Or the limit is "right" and something rare is happening? If so, please explain it with the corresponding "math".

Comment: I think your claim that $\lim_{x\to \infty} e^\sqrt{x}\text{sinc}(x)=0$ is not true. I think this graph clearly shows that the limit diverges https://www.desmos.com/calculator/4gyv9cjtng

Comment: The limit does not exist. Try approaching infinity along the sequences $x_n:=2\pi n$ and $y_n:=2\pi n+\pi/2$.

Comment: @AlanAbraham that was the first thing I did, but Wolfram-Alpha tells that the limit is zero, don´t knowing why - I left the link now on the question.

Comment: technically 0 is of the form "bounded function"/$x$, thus I think what you're saying is unintuitive is a bit wrong. instead, the issue is that $sinc(x) = 1/x$ infinitely often as $x\to \infty$, yet $\exp(\sqrt{x})/x \to \infty$.

Comment: WA justifies this by saying the function has a horizontal asymptote at zero, this is technically correct, if you at the limit as $x\to - \infty$, you do get zero. but the conclusion for the other direction is 100% wrong, idk why WA is saying it though.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's based on the false statement.

Comment: @BotnakovN. Thanks for your critic opinion. You are totally right, I will reformulate it to make them a valid question.

Comment: @BotnakovN. I don´t "really" know if is false, if you can explain why W-A is getting this "wrong" it will be awesome, of is something is happening that is somehow "true" against the evidence I left, it will be also useful.

Comment: @AlanAbraham I will incorporate your plot to the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to the last comment:

Gary has already given a proof that $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)$ for $f(x) = e^{\sqrt{x}} \frac{\sin x}{x}$ doesn't exist. I will try to explain in.

Indeed, put $x_n = 2\pi n+ \frac{\pi}2$, hence $f(x_n) = \frac{e^{\sqrt{2\pi n  + \frac{\pi}2   }}}{2\pi n+ \frac{\pi}2 } \to +\infty$ as $n \to \infty$.

Put $y_n= 2\pi n$ hence $f(y_n) = 0$. Hence the Heine limit $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)$ doesn't exists and hence the statement from the question is not true.

If any step in solution is not clear, I'll prove it.

Comment: Thanks for explaining it. I didn´t here before about "Heine limit" approach. I have the doubt about proving it for the function $f(x_n) = e^{\sqrt{2\pi n +\pi/2}}/(2 \pi n + \pi/2)$ is just proving that $e^{\sqrt{x}}/x$ diverges, instead of using another form which doesn't remove the $\sin(x)$ since is crossing $0$ infinitely many times, and in Wikipedia [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_function#In_terms_of_sequences) says Haine Limit $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=L$ exists if it converges for "all sequences $x_{n}$ (with $x_{n}$ not equal to "a" for all n)" not just "some" selected ones.

Comment: Sorry, I have understand now why are you explaining, since for one sequence is $0$ and for the other is not, then $L=0$ can´t be the limit, Is that so?.... I have added that W-A gives a finite value to the definite integral between $0$ and $\infty$... That is also wrong, isn´t it?

Comment: @Joako, we know that $g(x) = \frac{e^{\sqrt{x}}}{x} \to +\infty$ as $x \to +\infty$. Hence $g(z_n) \to +\infty$ for all $z_n$ such that $z_n \to +\infty$. Hence $g(x_n) \to +\infty$ for our sequence $x_n$ (we just take $z_n = x_n$).

Comment: So is reasonable to believe that $\int_0^\infty e^{\sqrt{x}}\text{sinc}(x)\,dx \to \infty$ instead of $\int_0^\infty e^{\sqrt{x}}\text{sinc}(x)\,dx = 3.41751$ as W-A says?

Comment: No, because $f(y_n) \to 0$ for $y_n = 2\pi n$. So we proved that the limit doesn't exist.

Comment: sorry, I don´t get it yet... Saying that the limit "doesn't exists" is different of saying that is $\infty$?? The result $\int_0^\infty e^{\sqrt{x}}\text{sinc}(x)\,dx = 3.41751$ is right or wrong?

Comment: You wrote $\int_{0}^{\infty}$ twice, so maybe it's not a misprint. What are we talking about: limits or integrals?

Comment: from the limits, I believe, if $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x) \to \infty \Rightarrow \int_0^\infty f(x)\,dx \to \infty$, but maybe I am wrong... since, If I am following you right, W-A is wrong because $\lim_{x \to \infty} e^{\sqrt{x}}sinc(x) \neq 0$, and $\lim_{x \to \infty} e^{\sqrt{x}} \to \infty$, then the other result of W-A: $\int_0^\infty e^{\sqrt{x}}sinc(x)\,dx = 3.41751$ is wrong, since in every positive half-period is summing a bit more and more that in its previous negative half-period... but the same argument can be said for the negative part, so is result must be or $-\infty$ or $\infty$

Comment: ... but not a finite number. This is why I am confused.

Comment: I didn't speak about integrals anywhere. I spoke only about limits and said only that $e^{\sqrt{x}} sinc(x)$ doesn't have limit, because it doesn't have Heine limit. But the integral also doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks you very much for your explanation.