# Wolfram-Alpha says that $\int_0^\infty e^{\sqrt{x}}\,\text{sinc}(x)\,dx = 3.41751$, Is this result right? Why?

Tags: limits, functions, convergence-divergence, definite-integrals, exponential-function

Wolfram-Alpha (W-A) says that $\int_0^\infty e^{\sqrt{x}}\,\text{sinc}(x)\,dx = 3.41751$ [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int_0%5Einf+%28e%5E%28sqrt%28x%29%29%29*sinc%28x%29*dx), Is this result right? Why?

Since W-A also says $\lim_{x \to \infty} e^{\sqrt{x}}\,\text{sinc}(x) = 0$ and is wrong following [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4281731/why-wolfram-alpha-w-a-said-that-lim-x-to-infty-e-sqrtx-cdot-textsi/4285092?noredirect=1#comment8919864_4285092) question, I wan't to know if the result of W-A for the integral is mistaken or not, but also know Why?

Comment: The result is wrong for the reasons given in the answer to your previous question. However, I have no idea why Wolfram Alpha gives returns this value (Mathematica also gives the same answer with NIntegrate). Perhaps looking at the Wolfram Mathematica documentation for [NIntegrate](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NIntegrateIntegrationStrategies.html) might help.

Comment: I can't see this integral converging as the integral keeps producing larger and larger contributions from, for example, intervals (of length $2\pi/3$) where $\sin x>1/2$. Mathematica version 11.2 says the same thing. *Does not converge on $(0,\infty)$*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result of Wolfram-Alpha is wrong as other notes in the comments. I left the answer to close the question.